# Highcharts - Unable to remove xasis titles while drill down

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart with drill down option. Drill up chart xaxis titles are dates. Values are poleted based on the date. While drill down the details of the data are being displayed.

While drilldown the dates which are displayed on the drillup is also diaplaying.

Unable to remove the xaxis title while drill down.

```html
{
"chart":{
    "width":800,
    "height":400,
    "defaultSeriesType":"column",
    "marginLeft":70,"marginTop":80},
"legend":{
    "align":"left",
    "layout":"vertical",
    "verticalAlign":"top",
    "x":100,"y":70},
    "plotOptions":{
        "column":{
            "borderWidth":0}},
"series":[{
    "data":[{
        "x":1.4345658E12,
        "y":3.0,
        "drilldown":"1.4345658E12"},
        {
        "x":1.4346522E12,
        "y":2.0,
        "drilldown":"1.4346522E12"}],
    "name":"All",
    "type":"column",
    "tooltip":{
        "xDateFormat":"%m/%d/%Y"}},
    {
    "data":[],
    "name":"Abcd",
    "type":"column",
    "tooltip":{
        "xDateFormat":"%m/%d/%Y"}},
    {
    "data":[],
    "name":"Efgh",
    "type":"column",
    "tooltip":{
        "xDateFormat":"%m/%d/%Y"}},
    {
    "data":[],
    "name":"Ijkl",
    "type":"column",
    "tooltip":{
        "xDateFormat":"%m/%d/%Y"}}],
"title":{
    "text":"Alphabet"},
"xAxis":[{
    "minTickInterval":8.64E7,
    "min":1.4343066E12,
    "max":1.4346522E12,
    "type":"datetime",
    "dateTimeLabelFormats":{
        "day":"%m/%d/%Y"},
    "title":{
    "text":"Date"},
    "id":"default"},
    {
    "type":"category",
    "id":"drilldown"}],
"yAxis":{
    "min":0.0,
    "title":{
        "text":"Count"}},
"drilldown":{
    "series":[{
        "data":[{
            "y":1.0,
            "name":"A1"},
            {"y":1.0,
            "name":"B1"},
            {"y":1.0,
            "name":"C1"}],
        "id":"1.4345658E12",
        "xAxis":"drilldown"},
        {
        "data":[{
            "y":1.0,
            "name":"A11"},
            {
            "y":1.0,
            "name":"B11"}],
        "id":"1.4346522E12",
        "xAxis":"drilldown"}]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide title, use `axis.showEmpty` option. However, there is bug in that option, when trying to hide axis **and** setting min and max for an axis.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vncnwd66/3/

Bug [report](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/705).